# Smooth Scroll to anchor edit page top

Tags: jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling, anchor-scroll

I am using a smooth scroll snippet. I have a fixed header, and would like the anchor sections to stop under my header. How would I edit this code to get them to stop roughly 100 pixels below the top of the page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var $target = $(this.hash);
  $target = $target.length && $target
  || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if ($target.length) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset(). top;
    $('html,body')
    .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
   return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

I just need the sections to stop 100px below the page top. I am very new to jquery so please bare with my lack of knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add `100` to the targets *offset from the top of the webpage* as such:

```
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top + 100;
    $('html,body')
    .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad :) Adding '+ 100' moved the "top" up, so I did '- 100' and this worked perfectly :) Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome @MattDelahoussaye, but don't forget the VOTE UP, and ACCEPT as well if it was indeed ACCEPTable :)

Comment: I'm very new to this site, so I am still learning the etiquette :) Voted and accepted! Thanks

Comment: could I ask another question to you?

Comment: I have sections, with tabbed boxes in them on my page. The scroll JS I am using to smooth scroll the sections is interfering with the tabbed boxes.
Would you know how to overcome this?

Comment: I think it would be better to post this in a new question and then share it's link with me in this section so that it's clear enough.